# How to mark a C++ type as not "trivially_copyable", while keeping it "trivial for the purposes of calls" in the Itanium C++ ABI?

Tags: c++, abi, itanium

I want my C++ type to expose a move-only interface, therefore I declared its copy constructor and copy assignment as deleted.
Nonetheless, the move constructor and move assignment are trivial, and the destructor is also trivial, therefore it is considered as "trivially_copyable" for the C++ standard.
This is a problem, because copying an object of this type really is semantically wrong.

A possible solution is to user-define an empty destructor that does nothing.
This makes the type not "trivially_copyable", but as a consequence the type is not longer "trivial for the purposes of calls" for the Itanium ABI, which can have negative performance implications.

Is there a way to achieve all these goals at the same time?
The type should have trivial move-constructor, move-assignment and destructor.
The type should not be trivially copyable.
The type should be trivial for the purpose of calls for the Itanium ABI.

Comment: "_This is a problem, because copying an object of this type really is semantically wrong._": How can that be? A trivial move constructor is equivalent to a `memcpy` of suitable range of the object representation.

Comment: Moving an object leaves the moved-from object in a valid but unspecified state in general. Trivial moves do not change the value of the moved-from object, but relying on any assumption to remain valid on the moved-from object is a bad practice, even if it happens to be that the move is trivial.

Comment: "*copying an object of this type really is semantically wrong*" - Why is copying a triviallygcopyable object wrong? Can you show an actual code example that you are having trouble with?

Comment: So the issue is that you are worried of a user testing that your type is trivially-copyable, then relying on that property to remain in the future? I would hope that noone relies on such properties without explicit permission, but potentially valid concern. It wouldn't be an issue in e.g. library functions that optimize based on `is_trivially_copyable`. The type would simply switch between the optimized and unoptimized path if the `is_trivially_copyable` property changes later.

Comment: In particular, invoking member functions that have preconditions on moved-from objects is often undefined behaviour, my type documents that you cannot call such member functions on the moved-from type even if the move constructor is trivial, I argue that this shouldn't be too surprising, because programmers avoid making any assumption about moved-from objects.

Comment: C++ `<type_traits>` defines two slightly different traits: `is_trivially_copyable` and `is_trivially_copy_constructible`. The later is more restrictive and requires the copy constructor to be present. There are a bunch of other similar, yet different traits too. Which one of them do you need to constrain your templates?

Comment: What does "copying an object of this type really is semantically wrong" mean? When you say move operations are trivial, that means memcpy should be a valid way to transport bit representations for this type. Trivially copyable doesn't imply copyable.

Comment: @Marco: "*In particular, invoking member functions that have preconditions on moved-from objects is often undefined behaviour*" But there's no actual implementation backing up that precondition. That is, there is no way to detect a "moved-from" object from a non-"moved-from" object. As such, your precondition isn't backed up by anything; there's no code that would *functionally* break from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#non-trivial

> A type is considered non-trivial for the purposes of calls if:
>
> - it has a non-trivial copy constructor, move constructor, or destructor, or
> - all of its copy and move constructors are deleted.

[[class.prop]p1](https://wg21.link/class.prop#1):

> A *trivially copyable class* is a class:
>
> - that has at least one eligible copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator,
> - where each eligible copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, and move assignment operator is trivial, and
> - that has a trivial, non-deleted destructor.

So all the copy/move constructors and the destructor have to remain non-trivial, so you can only make it not trivially copyable with a copy or move assignment operator. Since you want the move assignment operator to be trivial, that leaves a copy assignment operator:

```cpp
struct T {
    T(T&&) = default;
    T(const T&) = delete;
    T& operator=(T&&) = default;
    T& operator=(const T&) = delete;
    ~T() = default;
private:
    [[deprecated("To ensure T is not trivially copyable; should not be used")]] void operator=(const volatile T&);
};
```

---

This can also be solved with [`[[clang::trivial_abi]]`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#trivial-abi):

```cpp
struct [[clang::trivial_abi]] T {
    constexpr T(T&&) noexcept;
    T(const T&) = delete;
    T& operator=(T&&) = default;
    T& operator=(const T&) = delete;
    ~T() = default;
};

constexpr T::T(T&&) noexcept = default;
```

But that is only available with Clang (which modifies the definition of "non-trivial for the purposes of calls" to exclude classes with this attribute)

Answer (score 2):

You can make the move constructor trivial, but the move assignment non-trivial, i.e.

```
struct MyType {
    //...
    MyType(MyType&&) noexcept = default;
    inline MyType& operator=(MyType&&) noexcept;
    //...
};
inline MyType& MyType::operator=(MyType&&) noexcept = default;
```

For a type to be *trivially-copyable* all eligible non-deleted constructors, destructors *and* assignment operators must be trivial. However, the *trivial for the purpose of calls* property looks only at constructors and destructors.

> The type should have trivial move-constructor, move-assignment and destructor.

No, this requirement makes it impossible. You are basically asking the type to be trivially-copyable without it being trivially-copyable. Your requirements are basically the definition of that property.